# linked lists and function pointers

Tags: c++, linked-list, function-pointers

I am trying to learn about function pointers and linked lists.

In the class(as private) I have

```
int (*m_pointerToFunction)(int);
```

and

```
void List::apply_all( int (*pointerToFunction) (int)){
   m_pointerToFunction = pointerToFunction;
}
```

and

```
int triple(int i)
{
    return 3*i;
}
```

which is called with the list L2 with

```
L2.apply_all(triple);
```

What part am I missing in here? It doesn't seem to do anything with the nodes in the list.

*Edit:* Problem solved! As the comments and the answer, I never did anything with the nodes. I now iterates through the list and it works fine, thanks everybody :)

```
void List::apply_all( int (*pointerToFunction) (int)){
    Node *temp = head;
    while(temp){
        temp->value = pointerToFunction(temp->value);
        temp = temp->next;
    }
}
```

Comment: You have to iterate over your list and apply the function on each list item in some way. That code is missing.

Comment: Of course nothing is done with the nodes, you don't call the function pointer anywhere (that we can see).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's probably no need to actually store the function pointer in your `apply_all()` method. Rather, you need to setup a loop which iterates over each element in your list, and then calls the function pointer for each one. Judging by your `triple()` function, you probably want to store the result back in your list too, or else it won't do anything.

It's hard to give example code for that without knowing how the rest of your list class is structured. Basically though, you'd put something like this in a loop inside `apply_all()`:

```
nodevalue = pointerToFunction(nodevalue);
```

In case you're not aware, the C++ Standard Template Library actually includes all of this functionality already. There's the `std::list` class, along with functions like `std::transform()` and `std::for_each()` which can apply function pointers (or other callables) to each element.

You might also want to look at the `std::function` template, which was introduced in C++11. It makes function pointers a lot easier to work with!